# How to extend factory method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, factory

**Context:**

I have some class which at some point produces instances of itself, and it works fine.
But now I would like to extend that class and realize that I would get an instance of a parent class.

**Example:**

```
class Line {
    constructor(protected length: number) {}
    
    divide(into: number): Line[] {
        const size: number = Math.ceil(this.length / into);

        return (new Array(into)).map(() => new Line(size));
    }
}

class BoldLine extends Line {
    constructor(protected length: number, private width: number) {
        super(length);
    }

    getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
}

const line: BoldLine = new BoldLine(10, 2);

line.divide(2); // <== I'll get Line[] but would like to have BoldLine[];
```

**Question:**

How can I always get the instance of `this.constructor` class, even after inheritance?
And how can I do this in a seamless way, w/o passing constructor name as a parameter for `divide` method?

Thanks.

Comment: `this.constructor` will actually return you derived class constructor, but this approach is problematic because the base class doesn't know how to invoke this constructor (which arguments to pass)

Comment: @AlekseyL. also a problem is that the compiler doesn't recognise `this.constructor`. The arity of the constructor is still a problem, though. You can go around these with type assertions but it doesn't feel very clean. I can't think of a good way to implement this in TS without having to wrestle the type system.

Comment: Agree 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyCWA7AptA3gKGt6wD2iEALgE4CuwReJAFAA4l5HKXIAm0IyiA5kQBYAuaIjIBbAEbISASnTQAvhiw428AG7w2yGkirDRk6TOED4EANoBddCpw58hItAjwAXsgPipJaAF5oAFkwAQA6YGR4EBozCFCuXgFoAHpoPTwZAG47e2gSZCIyEkQRZAB3aABBEhIwAE9dRCoZUIAzKOiyRG12lDYWsTA6Gho5PwA+aFjw-JDkAEknMEQImlcPGSycpRzgWeZF4mXVhL4hEW9jU35zW1ycfMLi0oqEFBpTgTlIKZuIbPsSh2oEgMAAQngQGw3qhkAAPZjdGAwu4OAjEciUaj0RjMVgcT7nQw+AA00AYGjm0DKWgEXiMslR9wgZDo0g+3DOW0Bynse2Qc0ORGOOkJ9J8Jl+t0w92wjyKJRQFQhUJhHMS-DJ0xpbC+0B+sQBOCBykcxE4SE80BV0Mt-he1shtveAEYAAxkgBMWwwZshyHieB4H0toTUmm0NG9MiAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better approach, but this is how I would do it.

```
class Line {
    constructor(protected length: number) {}
    
    divide(into: number): this[] {
        const size: number = Math.ceil(this.length / into);

        return (new Array(into)).map(() => new (this.constructor as new (length: number) => this)(size));
    }
}

class BoldLine extends Line {
    constructor(protected length: number, private width) {
        super(length);
    }

    getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
}

const line: BoldLine = new BoldLine(10, 2);

line.divide(2);
```

If you need the `width` property (which is untyped so it could be anything, including undefined) to be propagated to child classes, then you need an additional factory method for instances of the current class.

```
class Line {
    constructor(protected length: number) { }

    protected create(length: number): this
    {
        return new Line(length) as this;
    }
    
    divide(into: number): this[] {
        const size: number = Math.ceil(this.length / into);

        return (new Array(into)).map(() => this.create(size));
    }
}

class BoldLine extends Line {
    constructor(protected length: number, private width) {
        super(length);
    }

    protected create(length: number): this
    {
        return new BoldLine(length, this.width) as this;
    }
    
    getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
}

const line: BoldLine = new BoldLine(10, 2);

line.divide(2);
```

Comment: The trouble here is that `width` is never passed in the child constructor.

Comment: Sure. Then you'd need a factory for a single instance of `this` class in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @GOTO0, I'll try to apply this on my real case but I feel optimistic after your help!
P.S. `width` is untyped just by mistake.